Xcode Cloud change locale via post_clone.sh
I'm converting a project to use Xcode Cloud, and some of our data unit tests are failing due to the timezone being different. Is there a way to convert or tell the cloud runners to change the time zone to the one we need?
Unfortunately, there's nothing online relating to our edge case on testing :(
We are using the ci_post_clone.sh to resolve some of our packages and I guess this would be the place to put the change timezone command??
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEPackageOnlyUseVersionsFromResolvedFile
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEDisableAutomaticPackageResolution

Expectation: All of our date tests match the conversion from the API.
